# How do I access civicrm.setting.php file?

Tags: wordpress, error, contribution-page

How do I access PHP files? I'm having the problem where when people try to click on a contribution page, this error comes up:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. We can't load
>   the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in
>   your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies
>   (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists,
>   contact the site adminstrator for assistance.
> Site
>   Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this
>   page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL.
>   EXAMPLE: Base URL is http:// example. org, but some users are
>   accessing the page via http://www. example. org or a domain alias like
>   http://myotherexample. org.
> Error type: Could not find a
>   valid session key.

I've found a few examples of the same thing happening and people keep suggesting that I make sure my base URL is the same as in the civicrm.setting. php file. I found the base URL (it looks fine, and we haven't changed the domain name or anything) but how do I access the file to compare it to? We're on Wordpress v 4.6.1.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is installed in standard, that file should be located here: `<wordpress>/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php`

Comment: I put it in as http://mywebsite.ca/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php but it just shows a blank page. Any other ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in cPanel!